# Unity add debuggable property to the manifest file after build

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-manifest

I am publishing an app to android, and the error: Debuggable Builds will not be accepted and the app manifest file must not contain any line item which states “android:debuggable”
appears,

I removed the debuggable property from the manifest file that Unity generated in the editor, but it seems like the property is added again during the build process, how can I control that, I tried exporting the project to android studio project, and I was able to modify the debuggable property, but there are many other errors appear, and we have to publish today,

Is there anyway to prevent Unity from adding the property debuggable after building the APK?

Thank You..

Comment: A silly suggestion, but did you uncheck the "Development build" in Build settings?

Comment: I did for sure, btw its not silly!

Comment: Then the next step will be to make sure, that you have signed your application. Take a look at keystore. (Publishing settings)